# Computed properties vs. persistent storage in Core Data and Swift

Tags: ios, database, swift, core-data

I have a feeling this is a silly question, but I'm new to this and I can't find a clear answer.

I have an Activity entity and a Sessions entity. Each Activity can have many Sessions. Each Session has a duration attribute.

Now I want the *average* session duration for an activity. Should I add an averageSessionDuration attribute to my Activity entity and update it and persist it when a user adds or deletes a session, or can I just add a computed property to my Activity class and have it calculate the average session duration whenever it's called?

I guess using a computed property the average session duration would be calculated a little more often than necessary, but I don't know if that matters, does it make a difference in the end?

I don't know what goes on behind the curtains, is fetching every session duration and taking the average a lot more expensive than just fetching an averageSessionDuration property that is updated when necessary and persisted? What are the best practices in this case? Is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Comment: Good question. @Animal is right. A computed property will be much cleaner and less likely to be incorrect. Only resort to storing the average if you observe real performance impacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are ever going to fetch on that property then you will want to persist it.  This is assuming a SQLite store.

If you are never going to fetch from it then a computed property is going to be cleaner.

That is the only question that is important for making that decision.

Comment: A computed property it is then. Thank you!

Comment: This is the better answer. The checkmark should belong to you

Comment: @Animal Ok then, you get an upvote for helping and for being a gentleman. ;)

Answer (score 3):

It most likely doesn't make any difference in performance but it would be cleaner code (I think) if you use a computed property instead of trying to make sure it's always up to date when you save other values.

If you are scared of performance issues you can always cache the calculated value every session and just invalidate the cache when you change values in the app. That might be the best of two worlds.

This is a question of taste and I'm sure there are arguments supporting both sides.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That was my first thought, but I wondered if it wasn't just me being lazy.